# Having trouble making game time pause and unpause

Tags: unity, c

I've been trying to make it where when the player does a certain task, the game's time will pause. When the player does another action, the game's time would unpause and continue. I had my code like so:

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class timeScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    //uGUI Items
    public Text date;
    public Text playerCash;

```
//Times
public static int week;
public static int month;
public static int year = 1980;
//amount of cash
public static int myCash = 10000;
public AlertBox alert;
public Text timeText;

bool timeActive = true;
int time;

int day;

void Start()
{
    InvokeRepeating("Timer", 0, 1);
}

public static void Timer()
{
    timeText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "W" + week.ToString() + "" + year.ToString();

    playerCash.GetComponent<Text>().text = "$" + myCash.ToString();


    #region YEAR
    //Check if month equals 13 (allows for 12th month to be counted)
    if (month == 13)
    {
        year++;
        month = 0;
    }
    #endregion
    #region MONTH
    //Check if week equals 5 (allows for 5th week to be counted)
    if (month == 5)
    {
        month++;
        week = 0;
    }
    #endregion
    #region WEEK
    //Check if day equals 8 (allows for 7th day to be counted)
    if (day == 8)
    {
        week++;
        day = 0;
    }
    #endregion
    #region DAY
    //Check if Time equals 5 (allows for 4 seconds)
    if (time == 2)
    {
        day++;
        time = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        time++;
    }
    #endregion
```

I tried using CancelInvoke(timeScript.Timer()); in another c# file but all it did was give me an error that stated I couldn't convert from string to void.

Comment: Try CancelInvoke("Timer") as per documentation http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.CancelInvoke.html